# Color Fill Under data line

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the data `income` plotted in graph [image: Income Graph]

I would like to fill in a color under the data line, I am using `qplot` for that.
Is there any possibility I can do that?
The code below shows shows how it was plotted, I do not mind using ggplot2 as well as long as I can fill under it

```
qplot(dat$amount_WW,dat$location, group = 1, geom=c("line","point"), ylab="amount",xlab="location",main="Ages 18-25")
```

Thank alot for your help

Comment: Could you please make your example reproducible? This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It worked! How to you change the color of the filling now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom=c("line","point", "area")`  and set the fill color using `fill`:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=runif(10))
qplot(x, y, data=df, geom=c("line","point", "area"), fill="red")
```